# React Native [iOS] notification with actions - I am not able to identify what action was selected

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, uilocalnotification

I am working on a react native project, where i need a notification with actions.

I am using this module for handling notifications: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications

Presenting the notification works fine, and you are able to select one of two actions. As seen here: [screenshot of notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riPYk.jpg)

When an option is selected or the notification is tapped the following event is triggered:

```js
Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened((notification, completion) => {
    console.log("Notification opened by device user", notification);

    // I need to identify action here
    // notification doesn't include anything i can use to identify the action

    completion();
});
```

But from here i cant figure out how to identify what action was selected. I have been searching though the documentation and examples for hours without finding an answer.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: which version of `react-native-notifications` are you using?

Comment: react-native-notifications 3.1.1